# How to toggle multiple panels from PrimeFaces?

Tags: primefaces, toggle, panel

I have a Datagrid, which is created dynamically and has 1 panel in each row. I set a widgetVar to my Panel to toggle all panels with a commandLink like this:

```
    <p:panel  style="text-align:center;" id="horizontalPanel" toggleable="true" collapsed="true" toggleOrientation="horizontal" name="panelForComments" widgetVar="panel">
          <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{panelView.onToggle}" />
            <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%" cellpadding="10">
                            // more stuff
            </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
```

Furthermore I have a commandLink which should open all my panels. It looks like this:

```
<p:commandLink value="hide"  onclick="PF('panel').toggle()" update="@form">
                                </p:commandLink>
```

The problem is that just the last panel in my datagrid is toggeled. Does anybody have an idea what to do to open/ close all panels the same time with the p:commandLink?

Comment: Widgetvars should be unique

Comment: how can i toggle all panels at the same time then? I need something to identify the panels.. but thanks for the hint

Comment: Simulate a click on all of them via jquery. So create some jquery selector that retrieves all of them and do a click on each

Answer (score 1):

My approach is create a `<div class="toggleable-panel">` to wrap all your toggleable panel and create a javascript function to toggle all.

```
function toggleAll()
{
    if($('#toggleAll_input').prop('checked'))
    {
        $('.toggleable-panel').each(function () {
            PF($(this).attr("data-widget")).collapse();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $('.toggleable-panel').each(function () {
            PF($(this).attr("data-widget")).expand();
        });
    }
}
```